# How to save the state of the stepper in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uistepper

I’m doing an app to be used as an inventory.

I need to know how to save the state of the stepper 
So if I or another user close the app, the state of the stepper won’t change.

My app is targeting multiple users, so if one user has changed the stepper state it will be saved and changed for other users.

Answer (score 1):

The main idea: save `UIStepper`'s `value`.

---

It depends on your needs how you should save it:

- If you have just one main stepper and this is the whole idea of your
  app, you can save `value` to `UserDefaults` and then retrieve it

  ```
  let stepper = UIStepper()

  // Saving
  UserDefaults.standard.set(stepper.value, forKey: "stepperValue")

  // Retrieving
  stepper.value = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "stepperValue")
  ```
- If you have various number of steppers and their values are also connected with some model, you should use `FileManager` to save encoded values of steppers or you can also use some database like CoreData or Realm.

Comment: I have multiple steppers but none of them connected to each other. And I think if I use the userDefults that will save the steeper value for the user itself in the user phone, but I want the value entered to be saved for all other users. I’m using common user without the need for sign up